# nginx stickiness using query parameters

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I am using NGINX for loadbalance my servers running on python+tornado.

The sessionID is passed on from the browser is in the URL instead of cookie header as there is a CORS domain issue. I need to bring stickiness based on the sessionID passed.

http:///getstatus?sessionID=123344 using the sessionID present in the URL, nginx must do sticky loadbalancing.

Any help appreciated .

Comment: Guyz this is a serious doubt , if u know please give me answer instead of down voting

Comment: This is not a good thing because you will have these URLs crawled by bots.

Comment: There is no host or port mentioned in the URL , also the sesionID is fake :)